# TYPO3 Fluid - 403 Error for Flux Collapse Script

Tags: typo3, http-status-code-403, fluid, typo3-8.x

I'm having a rather dumb problem with Typo3. I'm working on a page with a 8.7.8 installation and yesterday, I created a new Fluid content element for an accordion module. Everything worked fine, and I filled content into the accordion. Today, I applied tiny changes to enhance usability on the back end side and tried to fill more content into the accordion, now realizing that the backend of the accordion module had gotten incredibly slow, also the page including the module can't be viewed anymore, it's loading endlessly.

Browser console is telling me that it's getting an 403 error when trying to load `typo3conf/ext/flux/Resources/Public/js/fluxCollapse.js net::ERR_ABORTED` succeeded by `Uncaught Error: Script error for "FluidTypo3/Flux/FluxCollapse"` originating from require.js.

I can't say if this error appeared following my changes of today or actually existed before. But it seems to be the only hint for troubleshooting I have right now. So I reset the fluid template back to the state of yesterday where it was working, flushed caches, deleted the accordion record from the page, checked if the script even exists and is in the right place (I know that would be a 404, but I just wanted to check everything) - nothing helped, the behaviour stays the same, FluxCollapse error is still occuring. Checking the Network Tab of Chrome, I can see that there are tons of other scripts that are loaded correctly, it's just this single one.

I can't find any similar problem on Google or SO, and since I'm actually more of a front end guy I have to ask this - probably - dumb question. Got any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the slow backend, but the 403 error may be caused by some special configuration on your web server's virtual host. A 403 error means "forbidden" so it would appear something in the configuration or file system permissions is not allowing you to load the script file in question.

That's where I would look first.